# When using a Scala compiler plugin in sbt, how do you set a library dependency for the plugin?

Tags: sbt

I'm using a compiler plugin I wrote that depends on the Kyro serialization library.  When attempting to use my plugin I set this up in build.sbt (top-level) like this:

```scala
lazy val dependencies =
  new {
    val munit = "org.scalameta" %% "munit" % "0.7.12" % Test
    val kyro = "com.esotericsoftware" % "kryo" % "5.0.0-RC9"
  }

lazy val commonDependencies = Seq(
  dependencies.kyro,
  dependencies.munit
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies,
    Test / parallelExecution := false    
  )

addCompilerPlugin("co.blocke" %% "dotty-reflection" % reflectionLibVersion)
```

But when I compile my target project, I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError that it can't find Kyro.  I've added kyro to my dependencies, but since this is for the compiler, not my app, it's not picking that up.

How can I properly tell sbt about a dependency my plugin needs?

Comment: where do you have that line? and add other relevant parts of your build definition

Comment: updated question with more details